# PHP MySQL setting session on submit from table generated by MySQL

Tags: php, session-variables, mysql

So here is goes. I have a website that has a login. Upon a successful login, a session variable called user is created which contains an array of the userid, username, email and so on. Then from there I have links to other pages. What is giving me trouble is that I have a page called membership.php. This page does a select query for the userid, username, email and generates a table with all of the users. There is also a submit button beside each user that is entitled "Edit". When this button is clicked it redirects to a page edit_account.php. My goal here is when i click on the edit button, a session variable is created containing the userid of that specific user. Then when it redirects to the edit_account.php page I can use that session as part of my select statement to gather data from the table and then edit that users details. Below is a snipit of my code so you can see what I am talking about.

```
<?php 

// First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
require("common.php"); 

// At the top of the page we check to see whether the user is logged in or not 
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    // If they are not, we redirect them to the login page. 
    header("Location: ../../index.php"); 

    // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it, 
    // people can view your members-only content without logging in. 
    die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
} 

// We can retrieve a list of members from the database using a SELECT query. 
// In this case we do not have a WHERE clause because we want to select all 
// of the rows from the database table. 
$query = " 
    SELECT 
id,
        roleid, 
        username, 
        email 
    FROM user
"; 

try 
{ 
    // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
    // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 


// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 


if (isset($_POST['Edit'])) {


    $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
    header("Location: edit_account.php");

}

?> 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Registration</title>
<link href="../../css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>

        </h1>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="../adminindex.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <h2>
            Users
        </h2>
    <form action="" method="post">    
    <table border="0" align="left" cellpadding="25px">

        <tr> 
            <th>ID</th> 
            <th>Role ID</th> 
            <th>Username</th> 
            <th>E-Mail Address</th> 
        </tr> 

        <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 
            <tr> 
                <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['roleid']; ?></td> <!-- htmlentities is not needed here because $row['id'] is always an integer --> 
                <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo htmlentities($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td> 
                <td><input name="Edit" type="submit" value="Edit" /></td>
                <td><input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /></td>
            </tr> 
        <?php 
        endforeach; 
        ?>

         </tr>
     </table>  
     </form>

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Copyright ©  2013
    </div>
</div>



<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I believe the problem resides in the block of code:

```
    if (isset($_POST['Edit'])) {


    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    header("Location: edit_account.php");

}
```

But I have tried many things and nothing seems to work. Also on edit_account.php page I have this code at the top:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '</pre>';
```

which spits out everything in the session variable. When I select the submit button and it redirects, this is the output of the above code.

```
array(2) {
 ["user"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["username"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
    ["roleid"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["email"]=>
    string(15) "admin@admin.com"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help. Anything is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you are calling [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) on each of your pages.

Comment: Can you debug a little?  Use `var_dump` and make sure what you think is there is in fact there.  I'd also look at a tool like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/Features/http-https-traffic-recording) that lets you easily inspect the requests.

Comment: Okay so session_start() is being called in common.php which is included so that is fine or else it wouldnt pick up the "user" session. I used var_dump for the session variable. I know this is working because of the ["id"]=> NULL. I called my session 'id'. Also if i hard code in a number such as $_SESSION['id'] = 2; This works and it displays as 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you're basically building a form that looks (stripping out all the fluff html):

```
<form>
<input name="Edit" type="submit" value="Edit" />
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="foo" />
<input name="Edit" type="submit" value="Edit" />
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="bar" />
<input name="Edit" type="submit" value="Edit" />
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="baz" />
etc...
</form>
```

There's just **ONE** form, with multiple submit buttons, and multiple copies of the same hidden field with the same name. As such, PHP will use the **LAST** hidden `id` value to populate $_POST with. There is NO way for PHP to tell which of the many submit buttons was clicked, or that it should try to use the `id` value next to that one particular submit button - that's not how HTTP forms work.

You need something more like this:

```
<table>
<tr><td><form><input type="hidden" name="id" value="foo"><input type="submit"></form></td></tr>
<tr><td><form><input type="hidden" name="id" value="bar"><input type="submit"></form></td></tr>
<tr><td><form><input type="hidden" name="id" value="baz"><input type="submit"></form></td></tr>
etc..
</table>
```

Note now EACH row has its **OWN** form, with one submit button and one hidden field within. This way, only that **ONE** hidden field is submitted, and you'll get the proper `id` value showing up in your PHP code.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my "answer" to this question. let me know what you think

Comment: you don't need a `<form>` in every table cell. `<form>foo</form>` is pointless. there's no form fields, so nothing to submit.

Comment: Right I understand thank you. Do you have any idea why I would be redirecting to a blank page though?

Answer (score 0):

put form code in each table row not on the whole table a single form.

another problem is u login from admin account and u are making changes of the admin session variable so declare another session variable for it.

or u can also put the update code at the starting of the page that either the form is submited so update the user data than no need of making changes in the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is great. Thank you Marc B. Exactly what I was looking for. This is the html code:

```
        <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?> 
        <tr> 
            <td> <form action="" method="post"> <?php echo $row['id']; ?> </form> </td> 
            <td> <form action="" method="post"> <?php echo $row['roleid']; ?>  </form> </td>
            <td> <form action="" method="post"> <?php echo htmlentities($row['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> </form> </td>  
            <td> <form action="" method="post"> <?php echo htmlentities($row['email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> </form> </td>  
            <td> <form action="" method="post"> <input name="Edit" type="submit" value="Edit" /> <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /> </form> </td>

        </tr> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And I can successfully set a session using:

```
if (isset($_POST['Edit'])) {

$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];
header("Location: edit_account.php");

}
```

But it seems I have ran into another problem:( I also want to add a delete button on each row to delete that user account. Right now this is how it looks:

```
<td> <form action="" method="post"> <input name="Delete" type="submit" value="Delete" /> <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /> </form> </td>
```

And the php code used is:

```
if (isset($_POST['Delete'])) {

// Everything below this point in the file is secured by the login system 

// We can retrieve a list of members from the database using a SELECT query. 
// In this case we do not have a WHERE clause because we want to select all 
// of the rows from the database table. 
$query = " 
    DELETE 
    FROM user
    WHERE
        id = :id 
"; 

// The parameter values 
$query_params = array( 
    ':id' => $_POST['id'] 
); 

try 
{ 
    // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
}

catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 
    // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
    // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 


// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt->fetch(); 


    // This redirects the user back to the members-only page after they register 
    header("Location: ../adminindex.php"); 

    // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
    // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
    // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
    die("Redirecting to adminindex.php.php"); 


}
```

My problem is the redirection. When I click on the Delete button it actually runs the query but afterwards it just redirects to memberlist.php but the page is blank!? Why would this be happening? Is there something I am missing?I have tried changing the header location with no success. Thanks for the help!